# Wrap content around EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, word-wrap

I am using an `EditText` where I set a hint named "comment". However it is possible that the text I type in has less letters than "comment", so I would like the `EditText` to wrap around the text I type in - which it doesn't at the moment, unless I type in something that has more letters than my hint "comment".

**Example:**

|comment|  <-- represents the boundaries of the `EditText`, "comment" is the hint.

|test   |  <-- my text I type in; the hint disappeared, but the `EditText` doesn't wrap around my text, but still around the size of the hint.

How can I change that?

Comment: set exact android:layout_width to your EditText in dp. Or use layout_weight if you want something like percentage-of-a-screen logic

Comment: Will it still wrap around my text even if the text is longer than the dp-size of the EditText?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure but you can try thus.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etAddComment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="7"
    android:hint="comment">
</EditText>
```

Comment: Make sure the "ems" is equal to the number of characters of "hint" or minimum string length.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

set property `android:ems="yourhintlength"`

Answer (score 0):

faced same issue
very old question but I didnot find solution
my suggestion - just to remove hint if editText is not empty
if you will need hint later(for example, text from edittext was removed) - save your hint and restore it

```
override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            if (s.isBlank()) {
                if (isMultiLine) this@DataInputView.hintText = reserveHint
                ...
            } else {
                if (isMultiLine) this@DataInputView.hintText = ""
                ...
            }
        }
```